# Using a specific URL for a page within a multisite

Tags: 7, multi-sites

I have a multi-site that I've got setup with a page created for a client, but they wanted a specific URL to point to it. For example, client.mywebsite.com/content/client-page should be only shown as clientwebaddress.com.

It's only a single page, so there's no kind of login, or further links. I had it set up through my DNS to just forward and mask the URL, except that wasn't working properly for them. It seems that some people didn't get redirected for some reason.

I've been told by server tech there's something I should be putting in the sites.php file, but as far as I'm aware, if I put the clients URL into my sites.php file (and change the DNS accordingly) it would just mean that their URL would work as an alternative to mine.

I know this is a pretty niche question, but it's not sure that the server tech is right.

Is there another way to do what I'm after?

Comment: Why not just host raw HTML somewhere and point client's domain to it? It shouldn't be difficult to leach raw code for the one Drupal page. Or go with .htaccess Permanent Redirect (your host might have interface for redirects). Or try the Redirect module [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect).

Comment: That was my alternative, to just rip the page out and put it somewhere else, but there's quite a few javascript plugins I've got setup it's making use of etc so it's not just plain HTML. It was more just that the server tech seemed to make it seem like this was a common thing